# A THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason: Failed to create a WebGL2 context

Tags: three.js, webgl, gsap, webgl2

In desktop mode my code run properly but in mobile view it's give error like

THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason: Could not create a WebGL context, VENDOR = 0xffff, DEVICE = 0xffff, GL VENDOR = Qualcomm, GL_RENDERER = Adreno (TM) 308, GL_VERSION = 145.0, Sandboxed = no, Optimus = no, AMD switchable = no, Reset notification strategy = 0x8252, ErrorMessage = bind ToCurrentThread failed: .

A THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason: Failed to create a WebGL2 context.

Why I got this error in mobile view